# Thread locking vs creating a new object

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

The C# lock statement allows only one thread to access an object at a time.
In a Parallel.ForEach loop, wouldn't it be faster to create a new object (local variable) within the loop, rather than using a field variable, since that way no threads are ever blocked?
What would be the pros/cons of each way?

I am using the code below, it seems that creating a local var instead of using a lock on a field is slightly faster.

nb. There are 3 email strings in the toEmails variable.

```
//Method 1 with lock statement takes 14092ms
List<string> toEmails = getListOfToEmails();
Object locker = new object();
SmtpClient smtpClient = getSmtpObject();//smtpClient is used here as a field
Parallel.ForEach(toEmails, toEmail =>
{
    string emailBody = getEmailBody(toEmail);

    MailMessage mailMessage = getMailMesssageObject(emailBody, toEmail);

    lock (locker)
    {
        smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
    }
});

//Method 2 without lock statement (creating a new local var each iteration) takes 13947ms
List<string> toEmails = getListOfToEmails();
Parallel.ForEach(toEmails, toEmail =>
{
    SmtpClient smtpClient = getSmtpObject();//smtpClient is used here as a local var

    string emailBody = getEmailBody(toEmail);

    MailMessage mailMessage = getMailMesssageObject(emailBody, toEmail);

    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
});
```

Comment: If your shared object has some sort of unique state information that you care about, then you can't just make new ones.

Comment: And if I recall correctly TPL also supports thread local variables in its loops.

Comment: It's common to avoid continually creating heavy objects and threads completely by creating a pool of threads that create a 'heavy' each on startup and then loop around the pool queue, popping off data for the 'heavy.  Put another way, I would probably not use either of your alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this overload of `ForEach`:

```
Parallel.ForEach(toEmails, () => getSmtpObject() , (toEmail, state, smtp) =>
{
    SmtpClient smtpClient = smtp;

    string emailBody = getEmailBody(toEmail);

    MailMessage mailMessage = getMailMesssageObject(emailBody, toEmail);

    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);

    return smtp;
}, smtp => {});
```

Second argument is a delegate that you can use it to create thread local data. in each iteration of loop you will get local data and you can change it and return to next iteration.

Last argument is another delegate this will be called in end of every task

Comment: So hypothetically, say you had 9 iterations, and 3 threads were used to run 3 iterations each. 
This way is better because you would be creating only 3 SmtpClient objects, one for each thread, compared to one for each Task/iteration?

Comment: Yes. In this way you only create 3 smtp

Comment: where is the state variable being used?
And is there any need for the smtpClient variable? Couldn't you just use smtp?

Comment: state variable is a `ParallelLoopState` type. see `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate(v=vs.110).aspx`. Instead of `smtpClient` use `smtp`. It is only a reference and i like to use local variables instead of parameters.

Comment: why do you like to use local variables instead of parameters?
Isn't it better to use a parameter since you require less code?

But wait a minute, if you just use the parameter, how does the compiler know what type it is?

Comment: The second parameter is a `Func<TLocal> localInit`. When you write this lambda expression `() => getSmtpObject()` for that function, because the return type of `getSmtpObject()` is a `SmtpClient` compiler will require a `Func<TSource, ParallelLoopState, SmtpClient, SmtpClient>` for third parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In Simple **lock** is preferable when there is a shared resource. As in your case its quite simple that SMTP CLIENT is not used as a shared resource. so its quite safe if you create new object each time.